# How do I add a border radius to padding but not the image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a hover effect where a circle appears around an image when hovering. I am doing this by adding a background color and a 50% border radius when hovering. The circle appears but the image also has a border-radius on hover which I do not want to happen.

```
#nine-dots{
    width: 17x;
    height: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#nine-dots:hover {
    background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.334);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Before image:
[image]

After image: [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use clip-path instead of border-radius

```css
img {
  padding: 50px;
}

img:hover {
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/150/150">
```